# Altbeacon show major & minor

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

When we want to get minor and major with this code we get null in both , but in log we get the values :

when we want to get minor and major with this code we get null in both , but in log we get the values :

```
        Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
        Log.i(TAG,"The first beacon " + firstBeacon.toString() + " is about " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");
        Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see has minor id "+beacons.iterator().next().getId3());
        Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see has major id "+beacons.iterator().next().getId2());

        String minor = beacons.iterator().next().getId3();
        String major = beacons.iterator().next().getId2();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
ArrayList<Beacon> mylist = new ArrayList<Beacon>(beacons);
for (int j = 0; j < mylist.size(); j++) {
String rangedUUID = mylist.get(j).getId1().toString();
String rangedMajor = mylist.get(j).getId2().toString();
String rangedMinor = mylist.get(j).getId3().toString();
}
```

or you can replace this

```
String minor = beacons.iterator().next().getId3();
String major = beacons.iterator().next().getId2();
```

with

```
String minor = firstBeacon.getId3();
String major = firstBeacon.getId2();
```

**Because**

```
beacons.iterator().next()
```

give next beacon